# WebSocket connection error - Unexpected server response: 403 when using 'ws' package in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sockets, ws

```js
async function getLatestData() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const ws = new WebSocket("wss://sockets-example-app/t1");

    ws.on('connect', () => {
      console.log("connected");
    });

 

    ws.on('error', (err) => {
      console.error('WebSocket error:', err.message);
      reject(err);
    });
  });
}
```

I am attempting to use the ws package in Express.js to connect to a remote WebSocket server at "wss://sockets-example-app/t1". However, I'm encountering an error: "Unexpected server response: 403".

I have an async function getLatestData() that wraps the WebSocket connection within a Promise, and I'm listening for events such as 'connect' and 'error'. when `error` event fires it returns `Unexpected server response: 403`

I have checked the documentation of the remote WebSocket server, but I couldn't find any information regarding the "403" response. I've also verified that there are no network/firewall issues blocking the connection.

do I need to set headers manually? above socket works fine from browser when I am connecting it via `socket.io-client` library.

Comment: Did you figure it out yet